# ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to Fetch the Projects list from ADO using MyPAT and Powershell script as below:

```
$token = "PAT"
$url="https://dev.azure.com/adient/_apis/projects?api-version=4.1"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
$Projects = $response.value.name
ForEach( $project in $Projects) 
{
  $url1="https://dev.azure.com/adient/_apis/projects/$($project)?includeCapabilities=true&includeHistory=true&api-version=4.1"
  $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
  
  Write-Host "result= $($response1 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
  
 
}
$ActiveProjects = $response1 | ConvertFrom-Json

$ActiveProjects | FT
```

I am getting an error stating
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At line:15 char:32

- $ActiveProjects = $response1 | ConvertFrom-Json
- ```
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Can anyone please help me fetch the values of the JSON and wanted to convert some data from the JSON  into an excel ?

Comment: What is the content of ```$response1```? The documentation for ```Invoke-TestMethod``` says “When the request returns JSON strings, this cmdlet returns a PSObject representing the data.” So the ```Convert-FromJson``` if *probably* unnecessary - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#outputs

Comment: After the first `Invoke-RestMethod` you are using the returned object directly (e.g. `$response.value.name`). You should be able to do similarly for `$response1`, without the need for `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: Thank you @zett42 for your reply. After adding this $ActiveProjects = $response1.value.name

$ActiveProjects | Format-Table      The script ran and completed but am not able to see the formatted table output to get the contents. Can you please help me to get those and to export to an excel

Comment: Can you show the output from this line `Write-Host "result= $($response1 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`, sanitized if necessary? Also please add how the expected output should look like.

Comment: Note that ```$response1``` is being overwritten at each iteration of the ```foreach``` so it will only contain the *last* response afterwards. If you want *all* results you’ll need to accumulate them into a list / array…

Comment: result= {
    "id":  "1cb4efa4-81d3-4609-8a41-2fdb0f248629",
    "name":  "ALPM Training",
    "description":  "Project Owner : May Noack (anoackm) \n\nAgile training project\nBased on Agile process for OOTB configuration\n",

Comment: This is some part of the output for one item..there are 140 more array items and I need only few things like name,description etc...

Comment: @zett42, The expected output should be in excel contains of three columns Name,Description and Last updatetime extracted from the json output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample you have provided over comments below is something that you can try to achieve your requirement.

- I have concatenated all the Json Objects into array and then used  `| ConvertFrom-Json`.
- Since your requirement is to have only limited properties, I have used `Select-Object` and provided id, name and Last Update Time.
- Lastly, I have exported the file as csv.

Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$projects = $project1,$project2,$project3
$result = '['

ForEach($project in $projects) 
{
    $result=$result+$project+','
}

$result = $result.Substring(0, $result.Length - 1) +']' 
$result = $result | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object id,name,'Last updatetime'| Export-Csv -Path "merged.csv"
```

*Results:*

[image]